# MySQL Condition on the last five minutes

Tags: mysql, conditional-statements

Here is what i've got so far :

```
WHERE (ar.acl_res_name = 'RESSOURCES-GPE-N1-24/7' OR ar.acl_res_name = 'RESSOURCES-GPE-N1-8/20')    
AND YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME( a.entry_time )) = YEAR(CURDATE())
AND MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME( a.entry_time )) = MONTH(CURDATE())
AND DAY(FROM_UNIXTIME( a.entry_time )) = DAY(CURDATE())
AND HOUR(from_unixtime( a.entry_time )) = HOUR(CURTIME())
AND MINUTE(from_unixtime( a.entry_time)) = MINUTE(CURTIME() - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)
```

I just want to work on the past 5 minute and this seems to not do the work ...

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
WHERE (ar.acl_res_name = 'RESSOURCES-GPE-N1-24/7' OR ar.acl_res_name = 'RESSOURCES-GPE-N1-8/20')    
AND a.entry_time >= NOW() - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE
```